# Autotrigger Bootstrap multiselect onDropdownHide event using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-multiselect

How to auto trigger Bootstrap multiselect (onDropdownHide) event using Jquery?

Comment: Please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/248),
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle'); will trigger the onDropdownHide event